# PHP for echos an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble trying to echo each iteration of a particular part of an array.

Here are the clues.  I can't quite piece them together (since I don't yet know much about php arrays).

If I do the following:

```
<?php
$audiofile = simple_fields_value("audiofile");
echo $audiofile['url'];
?>
```

I get the URL of the file, which is what I want.
However, I have four different URL's (A "two-dimensional array", I believe?), and I want to echo each of them.

According to the Simple Fields documentation, I know that I need to change the second line to:

```
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
```

This leads me to change the php as follows:

```
<?php
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
for($i=0;$i<count($audiofile);$i++)
{
echo $audiofile[$i];
}
?>
```

But this only echoes "ArrayArrayArrayArray".

Which makes sense, because $audiofile is returning an array of info, FROM WHICH I only want the ['url'].

So, I tried the following:

```
<?php
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
for($i=0;$i<count($audiofile);$i++)
{
echo $audiofile['url'][$i];
}
?>
```

But that echoes null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `echo` use `var_dump($audiofile[$i]);`

Comment: Try echo $audiofile[$i]['url']

Comment: You may look at http://php.net/manual/fr/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: var_dump(simple_fields_values("audiofile")) and it should be more clear for you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have your array key order backwards is all.  Have you tried flipping ['url'][$i] into [$i]['url']?  Like this:

```
<?php
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
for($i=0;$i<count($audiofile);$i++) {
    echo $audiofile[$i]['url'];
}
?>
```

Comment: There I go looking for zebras.
This did it!!  You rock!

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
<?php
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
for($i=0;$i<count($audiofile);$i++)
{
    print_r($audiofile[$i]);
}
?>
```

or do a var_dump

```
<?php
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
for($i=0;$i<count($audiofile);$i++)
{
    var_dump($audiofile[$i]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not with a foreach construct?

```
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
foreach ($audiofile as $key => $value) {
    echo $audiofile[$key]['url'];
}
```

It's more handful than a `for` cycle, basically you haven't to count items and increment the index by yourself because `foreach` has been built ad hoc to iterate over php arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php